# Forward mail through two mx records

Tags: email, dns, html-email, web-hosting, zoho

I have a domain: ex. hello.it an the host provides free mail hosting that I need for only some employees (1@hello.it), for the others I have a Zoho subscription (2@hello.it). On the DNS panel MX is pointed to the host but I want it to ALSO point to Zoho. So that 1@hello.it doesn’t need any sub domain.

Thanks

Comment: Alberto, when my email server needs to send an email to someone @hello.it, where should that email be sent to?

Comment: If it is sent to 1@hello.it it should be sent to the host, while if it was for 2@hello.it it should go to Zoho

Comment: Email servers around the world can't maintain list of your users, so all you can do is have one MX record that will make all emails being sent to that one email server, and then make some configuration magic there to have emails for some users forwarded to another server. How to configure this depends on email server software (and ServerFault is probably better place to ask question about that)